# how to add data-mask in zend form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, data-masking

How to convert below html text field into zend form,

```
 <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">IP</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input placeholder="" data-mask="999.999.999.999" class="text login_input" type="text">
                            <span class="help-inline">192.168.110.310</span>
                        </div>
```

I use zend 1.2 ,my challenge is `data-mask="999.999.999.999"`how to add a zend form,

I give below code, but not working,

```
    $ipRange = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('ipRange');
    $ipRange->class = "text login_input";
    $ipRange->data-mask = "999.999.999.999";
    $ipRange->addValidator('Ip', array('allowipv6' => false));
    $ipRange->setDecorators(array('ViewHelper','Description'));
    $ipRange->setAttrib('required', 'required');
    $ipRange->setRequired(true);
    $this->addElement($ipRange);
```

Comment: You can add the `data-mask` attribute exactly the way you add `placeholder` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ipRange->setAttrib('data-mask', '999.999.999.999');
```